# Config error Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, shibboleth

I am trying to install and run **[Jetty 7](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/)** for the *Shibboleth Identity Provider* on my server, but i get this error:

```
[iam@web333 jetty]$ java -jar start.jar jetty.port=27335
2013-06-29 12:01:47.490:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:Config error at <Call name="addConnector">|    <Arg>|      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector">|         <Arg>|           <New class="net.shibboleth.utilities.jetty7.DelegateToApplicationSslContextFactory">|             <Set name="keyStore">/home/iam/opt/shibboleth-idp/credentials/idp.jks</Set>|             <Set name="keyStorePassword">*****</Set>|           </New>|          </Arg>|        <Set name="port">27335</Set>|        <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>|      </New>|    </Arg>|  </Call> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.shibboleth.utilities.jetty7.DelegateToApplicationSslContextFactory
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.shibboleth.utilities.jetty7.DelegateToApplicationSslContextFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.nodeClass(XmlConfiguration.java:354)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.newObj(XmlConfiguration.java:754)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.itemValue(XmlConfiguration.java:1126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.value(XmlConfiguration.java:1029)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.newObj(XmlConfiguration.java:777)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.itemValue(XmlConfiguration.java:1126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.value(XmlConfiguration.java:1029)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.call(XmlConfiguration.java:722)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:296)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1247)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1182)
```

I followed this guide: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/IdPJetty7Prepare and i modify the ports 8080 and 8443 to my port 27335 in the **jetty.xml** and **jetty-ssl.xml** config files.

And also in **shib-delegatessl.xml** i have modified the port 8443 to 27335.

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  <Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector">
         <Arg>
           <New class="net.shibboleth.utilities.jetty7.DelegateToApplicationSslContextFactory">
             <Set name="keyStore">/home/iam/opt/shibboleth-idp/credentials/idp.jks</Set>
             <Set name="keyStorePassword">********</Set>
           </New>
          </Arg>
        <Set name="port">27335</Set>
        <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

How do I fix this error? and how can i test Jetty if it works?
Thank you very much.

Best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jar containing the `net.shibboleth.utilities.jetty7.DelegateToApplicationSslContextFactory` class needs to be in the server classpath.

Do this:

1. Put the shibboleth jars into the `${jetty.home}/lib/ext` directory.
2. Test that they are present on the server classpath by executing the following command.

   `$ java -jar start.jar --list-config`
3. Start Jetty like you did before.

Comment: I have copied the _xalan_ and _xerces_ jars from `${shibboleth-idp.home}/lib/endorsed` to `${jetty.home}/lib/endorsed`. Then i tried to Start Jetty but i get the same error. There are many other jars in `${shibboleth-idp.home}/lib`, does i need to copy them to `${jetty.home}/lib/ext`?

Comment: There is no such thing as a `${jetty.home}/lib/endorsed`, jetty doesn't know about, use, or even have a configuration for `${jetty.home}/lib/endorsed`.  I cannot comment on specifics of the shibboleth product and what its requirements are.  My answer is specific to address the error you got while using Jetty.

Comment: I called it in **start.ini** with `-Djava.endorsed.dirs=lib/endorsed` as described here: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/plugins/viewsource/viewpagesrc.action?pageId=5734962

Comment: The error you reported in your question has no indication that it has anything to do with the xerces or xalan libraries.  Focus on step #1 in that link you pasted to wiki.shibboleth.net, it indicates the specific jar you need to put into the `${jetty.home}/lib/ext` directory.

Comment: +1 for the --version command to show what is on the classpath. I am sure I have read that a dozen times. I am starting to see the getting started guides assume that everything is set up perfectly which is correct. IoC is a great concept once one has spent several years figuring it all out.

Answer (score 1):

probably this might help:
https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/IdPJetty7Prepare

What libs to copy and where is specified there.